# Unable to get user id to resource server client

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

My service already gets JWT token in request(so I don't need to write Resource Owner or Authorization server) and by interacting with Authorization server API it validates token. Now I want to know the user name/id in controller which I am unable to achieve. I tried using Authentication and principal everything but in my case this doesn't work. Here's my code:

> ResourceServerSecurity.java

```
    @Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class SecurityConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Value("${security.oauth2.resource.id}")
    private String resourceId;

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().mvcMatchers("/api/v1/**").authenticated().anyRequest().permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources.resourceId(resourceId);
    }
```

> Controller.java -I've tried to get user name using everything but I'm getting null

```
@GetMapping(value = "api/v1/testStatus")
public ResponseEntity<String> testStatus(OAuth2Authentication auth, Principal principal, @AuthenticationPrincipal User user) {
    System.out.println("auth:" + auth);
    System.out.println(("principal:" + principal));
    System.out.println(user);
    Object obj = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

    if (obj instanceof UserDetails) {
      String username = ((UserDetails)obj).getUsername();
    } else {
      String username = obj.toString();
    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok("Test");
}
```

Anybody's help would be much appreciated.